# Setting hook without calling external function

Tags: hooks

I am changing the default value for `fill-column`, then hook it for `prog-mode`.  Would be neat to have a way that I can have a single function to do this.  Currently `add-hook` requires a call to an outside function `colum-property` in order to set it.

```
(defun colum-property ()
  (setq fill-column 72))

(defun colum-mhook ()
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'colum-property))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the hook with a lambda function.

```
(defun colum-mhook ()
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda()(setq fill-column 72))))
```

As NickD rightly points out, encapsulating the add-hook in a function doesn't seem to help much.
You might as well write the add-hook directly in the Emacs initialization file.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing but also to remark that doing this makes it a bit more tricky to undo via `remove-hook`.

Comment: @Fran Burstall: `(remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook  (lambda()(setq fill-column 72)))` do the trick as if it is a named function.

Comment: Why is `colum-mhook` (sic) needed at all? Why not call `add-hook` directly?